# Real time web scraping with Java

Tags: java, web, web-scraping

I have already done a demo program to scrape through static websites, but what about websites that continuously change their data? 
ex. https://www.oanda.com/currency/live-exchange-rates/

How should I approach my problem?

The only way that comes in mind is to send 200 requests per second but wont I get banned?

How does the browser deal with such websites and how can I replicate that in Java code?

Comment: That website provides API for exchange rate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick answer is a headless browser.  Most of those sites serve up new information via a socket/ ajax/ asynch w/ page load approach.  So to be able to crawl dynamic sites you are absolutely right, the easiest way to do that is to behave more like a browser than a script.  There are plenty of ways to do that with selenium or phantomjs.  Normally people will use something like nutch to control the crawling flow at scale.  You may also want to look into a proxy farm.

Answer (score 0):

The browser is performing a data request once per timeframe at https://www.oanda.com/lfr/rates_lrrr. Instead of parsing html pages, you should try to figure out their data API.

Comment: Yes you are right , it was a bad example. What about a website like https://liveclock.net/ ??

Answer (score 0):

Selenium Web Driver is awesome.

Download Selenium jar and include in your build path: https://www.seleniumhq.org/download/
Download ChromeDriver from here: http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;

public class ExchangeRates {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        //Chrome Driver
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

        //Internet Explorer Driver
        //System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe");
        //WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();

        driver.get("https://www.oanda.com/currency/live-exchange-rates/");
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            getExchangeRates(driver);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        driver.close();
    }

    private static void getExchangeRates(WebDriver driver) {
        String exchangeRateJSON = runJavascript(driver, "var rateRows = $('.rate_row'); " + 
                                                        "var exchangeRates = []; " + 
                                                        "for(var i = 0; i < rateRows.length; i++) { " + 
                                                        "   var row = $(rateRows[i]); " + 
                                                        "   var lbls = row.find(\".inline.title.left a\"); " + 
                                                        "   var vals = row.find(\".inline.value.right\"); " + 
                                                        "   var lbl1 = $(lbls[0]).text(); " + 
                                                        "   var lbl1Parts = lbl1.split(\"/\"); " + 
                                                        "   exchangeRates.push({ " + 
                                                        "       fromCur:lbl1Parts[0], " + 
                                                        "       toCur:lbl1Parts[1], " + 
                                                        "       bid:parseFloat($(vals[1]).text()), " + 
                                                        "       ask:parseFloat($(vals[0]).text()) " + 
                                                        "   }); " + 
                                                        "   var lbl2 = $(lbls[1]).text(); " + 
                                                        "   var lbl2Parts = lbl2.split(\"/\"); " + 
                                                        "   exchangeRates.push({ " + 
                                                        "       fromCur:lbl2Parts[0], " + 
                                                        "       toCur:lbl2Parts[1], " + 
                                                        "       bid:parseFloat($(vals[3]).text()), " + 
                                                        "       ask:parseFloat($(vals[2]).text()) " + 
                                                        "   }); " + 
                                                        "} " + 
                                                        "return JSON.stringify(exchangeRates);");
        System.out.println(exchangeRateJSON);
    }
    public static String runJavascript(WebDriver driver, String script) {
        WebElement body = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body"));
        return (String)((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(script, body);
    }
}
```

The basic premise of Selenium Webdriver is that you can open a webpage and then perfrom actions like running Javascript in the context of the page.  This will prevent you from being detected as a bot.

The JSON the javascript returns looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "fromCur": "EUR",
    "toCur": "USD",
    "bid": 1.13949,
    "ask": 1.13962
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "USD",
    "toCur": "EUR",
    "bid": 0.87749,
    "ask": 0.87759
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "GBP",
    "toCur": "USD",
    "bid": 1.27602,
    "ask": 1.27619
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "USD",
    "toCur": "GBP",
    "bid": 0.78358,
    "ask": 0.78369
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "USD",
    "toCur": "CAD",
    "bid": 1.31391,
    "ask": 1.31408
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "CAD",
    "toCur": "USD",
    "bid": 0.76099,
    "ask": 0.76109
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "USD",
    "toCur": "CHF",
    "bid": 0.9936,
    "ask": 0.99379
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "CHF",
    "toCur": "USD",
    "bid": 1.00625,
    "ask": 1.00644
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "USD",
    "toCur": "JPY",
    "bid": 110.752,
    "ask": 110.765
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "JPY",
    "toCur": "USD",
    "bid": 0.00903,
    "ask": 0.00903
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "EUR",
    "toCur": "GBP",
    "bid": 0.89291,
    "ask": 0.89308
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "GBP",
    "toCur": "EUR",
    "bid": 1.11972,
    "ask": 1.11993
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "EUR",
    "toCur": "CHF",
    "bid": 1.13236,
    "ask": 1.13252
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "CHF",
    "toCur": "EUR",
    "bid": 0.88299,
    "ask": 0.88311
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "AUD",
    "toCur": "USD",
    "bid": 0.72642,
    "ask": 0.72654
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "USD",
    "toCur": "AUD",
    "bid": 1.37639,
    "ask": 1.37661
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "EUR",
    "toCur": "JPY",
    "bid": 126.207,
    "ask": 126.226
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "JPY",
    "toCur": "EUR",
    "bid": 0.00792,
    "ask": 0.00792
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "GBP",
    "toCur": "JPY",
    "bid": 141.328,
    "ask": 141.355
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "JPY",
    "toCur": "GBP",
    "bid": 0.00707,
    "ask": 0.00708
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "EUR",
    "toCur": "AUD",
    "bid": 1.56854,
    "ask": 1.56877
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "AUD",
    "toCur": "EUR",
    "bid": 0.63744,
    "ask": 0.63754
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "EUR",
    "toCur": "CZK",
    "bid": 25.75355,
    "ask": 25.78107
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "CZK",
    "toCur": "EUR",
    "bid": 0.03879,
    "ask": 0.03883
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "EUR",
    "toCur": "HUF",
    "bid": 323.69,
    "ask": 324.089
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "HUF",
    "toCur": "EUR",
    "bid": 0.00309,
    "ask": 0.00309
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "EUR",
    "toCur": "NZD",
    "bid": 1.73338,
    "ask": 1.73374
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "NZD",
    "toCur": "EUR",
    "bid": 0.57679,
    "ask": 0.57691
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "EUR",
    "toCur": "SEK",
    "bid": 10.39725,
    "ask": 10.39991
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "SEK",
    "toCur": "EUR",
    "bid": 0.09615,
    "ask": 0.09618
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "EUR",
    "toCur": "SGD",
    "bid": 1.56877,
    "ask": 1.5692
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "SGD",
    "toCur": "EUR",
    "bid": 0.63727,
    "ask": 0.63744
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "EUR",
    "toCur": "CAD",
    "bid": 1.49727,
    "ask": 1.49748
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "CAD",
    "toCur": "EUR",
    "bid": 0.66779,
    "ask": 0.66788
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "EUR",
    "toCur": "DKK",
    "bid": 7.45298,
    "ask": 7.45446
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "DKK",
    "toCur": "EUR",
    "bid": 0.13415,
    "ask": 0.13417
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "EUR",
    "toCur": "NOK",
    "bid": 9.53927,
    "ask": 9.54229
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "NOK",
    "toCur": "EUR",
    "bid": 0.1048,
    "ask": 0.10483
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "EUR",
    "toCur": "PLN",
    "bid": 4.31208,
    "ask": 4.31726
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "PLN",
    "toCur": "EUR",
    "bid": 0.23163,
    "ask": 0.23191
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "EUR",
    "toCur": "TRY",
    "bid": 7.95697,
    "ask": 7.97624
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "TRY",
    "toCur": "EUR",
    "bid": 0.12537,
    "ask": 0.12568
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "EUR",
    "toCur": "ZAR",
    "bid": 16.43966,
    "ask": 16.4571
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "ZAR",
    "toCur": "EUR",
    "bid": 0.06076,
    "ask": 0.06083
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "USD",
    "toCur": "CNH",
    "bid": 6.90501,
    "ask": 6.90585
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "CNH",
    "toCur": "USD",
    "bid": 0.1448,
    "ask": 0.14482
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "USD",
    "toCur": "DKK",
    "bid": 6.53998,
    "ask": 6.5415
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "DKK",
    "toCur": "USD",
    "bid": 0.15287,
    "ask": 0.15291
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "USD",
    "toCur": "HUF",
    "bid": 284.084,
    "ask": 284.37
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "HUF",
    "toCur": "USD",
    "bid": 0.00352,
    "ask": 0.00352
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "USD",
    "toCur": "MXN",
    "bid": 19.1822,
    "ask": 19.18824
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "MXN",
    "toCur": "USD",
    "bid": 0.05212,
    "ask": 0.05213
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "USD",
    "toCur": "PLN",
    "bid": 3.78415,
    "ask": 3.78769
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "PLN",
    "toCur": "USD",
    "bid": 0.26401,
    "ask": 0.26426
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "USD",
    "toCur": "SEK",
    "bid": 9.12374,
    "ask": 9.12617
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "SEK",
    "toCur": "USD",
    "bid": 0.10958,
    "ask": 0.1096
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "USD",
    "toCur": "THB",
    "bid": 33.316,
    "ask": 33.434
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "THB",
    "toCur": "USD",
    "bid": 0.02991,
    "ask": 0.03002
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "USD",
    "toCur": "ZAR",
    "bid": 14.42721,
    "ask": 14.44086
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "ZAR",
    "toCur": "USD",
    "bid": 0.06925,
    "ask": 0.06931
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "USD",
    "toCur": "CZK",
    "bid": 22.60223,
    "ask": 22.61947
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "CZK",
    "toCur": "USD",
    "bid": 0.04421,
    "ask": 0.04424
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "USD",
    "toCur": "HKD",
    "bid": 7.84967,
    "ask": 7.85
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "HKD",
    "toCur": "USD",
    "bid": 0.12739,
    "ask": 0.12739
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "USD",
    "toCur": "INR",
    "bid": 69.997,
    "ask": 70.102
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "INR",
    "toCur": "USD",
    "bid": 0.01426,
    "ask": 0.01429
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "USD",
    "toCur": "NOK",
    "bid": 8.3705,
    "ask": 8.37378
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "NOK",
    "toCur": "USD",
    "bid": 0.11942,
    "ask": 0.11947
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "USD",
    "toCur": "SAR",
    "bid": 3.7495,
    "ask": 3.75125
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "SAR",
    "toCur": "USD",
    "bid": 0.26658,
    "ask": 0.2667
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "USD",
    "toCur": "SGD",
    "bid": 1.37673,
    "ask": 1.37695
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "SGD",
    "toCur": "USD",
    "bid": 0.72624,
    "ask": 0.72636
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "USD",
    "toCur": "TRY",
    "bid": 6.97585,
    "ask": 7.00085
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "TRY",
    "toCur": "USD",
    "bid": 0.14284,
    "ask": 0.14335
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "GBP",
    "toCur": "AUD",
    "bid": 1.75644,
    "ask": 1.75679
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "AUD",
    "toCur": "GBP",
    "bid": 0.56922,
    "ask": 0.56933
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "GBP",
    "toCur": "CHF",
    "bid": 1.26798,
    "ask": 1.26827
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "CHF",
    "toCur": "GBP",
    "bid": 0.78848,
    "ask": 0.78866
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "GBP",
    "toCur": "ZAR",
    "bid": 18.4094,
    "ask": 18.42928
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "ZAR",
    "toCur": "GBP",
    "bid": 0.05426,
    "ask": 0.05432
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "GBP",
    "toCur": "SGD",
    "bid": 1.75673,
    "ask": 1.75725
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "SGD",
    "toCur": "GBP",
    "bid": 0.56907,
    "ask": 0.56924
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "AUD",
    "toCur": "JPY",
    "bid": 80.454,
    "ask": 80.47
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "JPY",
    "toCur": "AUD",
    "bid": 0.01243,
    "ask": 0.01243
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "AUD",
    "toCur": "SGD",
    "bid": 1.00008,
    "ask": 1.00041
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "SGD",
    "toCur": "AUD",
    "bid": 0.99959,
    "ask": 0.99992
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "CAD",
    "toCur": "JPY",
    "bid": 84.284,
    "ask": 84.301
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "JPY",
    "toCur": "CAD",
    "bid": 0.01186,
    "ask": 0.01186
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "CHF",
    "toCur": "JPY",
    "bid": 111.446,
    "ask": 111.472
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "JPY",
    "toCur": "CHF",
    "bid": 0.00897,
    "ask": 0.00897
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "NZD",
    "toCur": "CAD",
    "bid": 0.86359,
    "ask": 0.86388
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "CAD",
    "toCur": "NZD",
    "bid": 1.15757,
    "ask": 1.15796
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "NZD",
    "toCur": "USD",
    "bid": 0.65731,
    "ask": 0.65746
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "USD",
    "toCur": "NZD",
    "bid": 1.52101,
    "ask": 1.52135
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "SGD",
    "toCur": "JPY",
    "bid": 80.432,
    "ask": 80.455
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "JPY",
    "toCur": "SGD",
    "bid": 0.01243,
    "ask": 0.01243
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "ZAR",
    "toCur": "JPY",
    "bid": 7.666,
    "ask": 7.681
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "JPY",
    "toCur": "ZAR",
    "bid": 0.13019,
    "ask": 0.13045
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "GBP",
    "toCur": "CAD",
    "bid": 1.67665,
    "ask": 1.67698
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "CAD",
    "toCur": "GBP",
    "bid": 0.59631,
    "ask": 0.59643
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "GBP",
    "toCur": "NZD",
    "bid": 1.94104,
    "ask": 1.94156
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "NZD",
    "toCur": "GBP",
    "bid": 0.51505,
    "ask": 0.51519
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "GBP",
    "toCur": "PLN",
    "bid": 4.82832,
    "ask": 4.83505
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "PLN",
    "toCur": "GBP",
    "bid": 0.20682,
    "ask": 0.20711
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "AUD",
    "toCur": "CAD",
    "bid": 0.95447,
    "ask": 0.95468
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "CAD",
    "toCur": "AUD",
    "bid": 1.04747,
    "ask": 1.0477
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "AUD",
    "toCur": "NZD",
    "bid": 1.10499,
    "ask": 1.10529
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "NZD",
    "toCur": "AUD",
    "bid": 0.90474,
    "ask": 0.90499
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "CAD",
    "toCur": "CHF",
    "bid": 0.75611,
    "ask": 0.75636
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "CHF",
    "toCur": "CAD",
    "bid": 1.32212,
    "ask": 1.32256
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "CAD",
    "toCur": "SGD",
    "bid": 1.0477,
    "ask": 1.04801
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "SGD",
    "toCur": "CAD",
    "bid": 0.95419,
    "ask": 0.95447
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "CHF",
    "toCur": "ZAR",
    "bid": 14.51736,
    "ask": 14.53388
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "ZAR",
    "toCur": "CHF",
    "bid": 0.0688,
    "ask": 0.06888
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "NZD",
    "toCur": "JPY",
    "bid": 72.797,
    "ask": 72.82
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "JPY",
    "toCur": "NZD",
    "bid": 0.01373,
    "ask": 0.01374
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "NZD",
    "toCur": "SGD",
    "bid": 0.90493,
    "ask": 0.90529
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "SGD",
    "toCur": "NZD",
    "bid": 1.10462,
    "ask": 1.10506
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "TRY",
    "toCur": "JPY",
    "bid": 15.823,
    "ask": 15.864
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "JPY",
    "toCur": "TRY",
    "bid": 0.06304,
    "ask": 0.0632
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "XAG",
    "toCur": "JPY",
    "bid": 1663.5,
    "ask": 1665.5
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "JPY",
    "toCur": "XAG",
    "bid": 0.0006,
    "ask": 0.0006
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "XAU",
    "toCur": "JPY",
    "bid": 132176,
    "ask": 132220
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "JPY",
    "toCur": "XAU",
    "bid": 0.00001,
    "ask": 0.00001
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "XAG",
    "toCur": "USD",
    "bid": 15.01958,
    "ask": 15.03569
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "USD",
    "toCur": "XAG",
    "bid": 0.06651,
    "ask": 0.06658
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "XAU",
    "toCur": "USD",
    "bid": 1193.441,
    "ask": 1193.691
  },
  {
    "fromCur": "USD",
    "toCur": "XAU",
    "bid": 0.00084,
    "ask": 0.00084
  }
]
```